# Java regex not working for operand groups of possible values

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to write a Java method that will determine (true or false) if a particular String matches a regex of `animal<L_OPERAND,R_OPERAND>`, where `L_OPERAND` can be any of the following values: `dog`, `cat`, `sheep` and `R_OPERAND` can be any one of the following values: `red`, `blue`. All values are **case- and whitespace-sensitive**.

Some examples:

```
animal<fizz,cat>          =>    false; fizz is not a valid L_OPERAND value
animAl<dog,blue>          =>    false; animAl contains an upper-case char (illegal)
animal<dog,sheep>         =>    false; sheep is not a valid R_OPERAND value
animal<dog, blue>         =>    false; contains whitespace between ',' and 'blue' (no whitesapce allowed)
animal<dog,blue>          =>    true; valid
animal<cat,red>           =>    true; valid
animal<sheep,blue>        =>    true; valid
```

My best attempt so far:

```
public class RegexExperiments {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = new RegexExperiments().isValidAnimalDef("animal<dog,blue>");
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public boolean isValidAnimalDef(String animalDef) {
        String regex = "animal<[dog,cat,sheep],[red,blue]>";
        if(animalDef.matches(regex)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Although I'm not getting any exceptions, I'm getting `false` for every type of input string (`animalDef`) I pass in. So obviously my regex is bad. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Comment: `[dog,cat,sheep]` matches a single one of the listed characters, what you probably want is an alternation like `(dog|cat|sheep)`

Comment: Thanks and +1! Turn it into answer and the green check is yours!

Comment: @SebastianProske: you may post an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies within the `[dog,cat,sheep]` and `[red,blue]` structures. `[]` represent a character class, it matches a single character that is contained inside. For the first one this would be `,acdeghopst` and for the second `,bdelru`. So you currently match strings like `animal<d,b>` or even `animal<,,,>`.

What you are after is a mix of a grouping structure and an alternation. Alternations are provided by `|`, so e.g. `dog|cat|sheep` would match `dog` or `cat` or `sheep`. As you want this alternation inside a larger pattern, you have to contain it inside a group. The (for this case) simpliest grouping structure is a capturing group which is starting with `(` and ending with `)`.

Your final pattern could then be `animal<(dog|cat|sheep),(red|blue)>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String regex = "animal<(dog|cat|sheep),(red|blue)>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx `animal<(dog|cat|sheep),(red|blue)>`

**Output**

```
false
false
false
false
true
true
true
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(filterOut("animal<fizz,cat>"));
        System.out.println(filterOut("animAl<dog,blue>"));
        System.out.println(filterOut("animal<dog,sheep>"));
        System.out.println(filterOut("animal<dog, blue>"));
        System.out.println(filterOut("animal<dog,blue>"));
        System.out.println(filterOut("animal<cat,red>"));
        System.out.println(filterOut("animal<sheep,blue>"));
    }

    public static boolean filterOut(String str) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("animal<(dog|cat|sheep),(red|blue)>").matcher(str);
        if (m.find()) return true;
        else          return false;
    }
}
```